# Set cookie fails for first time but works on refresh

Tags: php, cookies

Though after reading explanations about setting cookie and not working for first time i find it difficult to resolve the below problem as am new to php and cookies.

I have a webpage with for (e.g) cp.php, login.php, header.php, maindata.php , bottom.php. Whenever i login to the webpage cp.php will be processed from there 1.header.php will be called first 2.maindata.php will be called and 3.bottom.php will be called.

So am setting my cookie at maindata.php and the code is like,

```
      <?php
      $cid =  $_GET["id"];
      $XmlPath =  $_GET["path"];
      $numpath  = $_GET["numpath"];
      $finepath =$_GET["finepath"];
      $Tech =$_GET["tech"];
      $read_str="";


    function read($Path)
    {
            $temp="";
            if(file_exists($Path))
            {
             $library = new SimpleXMLElement($Path,null,true);  

                            foreach($library->children("SAS") as $info){        
                                foreach($info->children("SAS") as $attributes){                             
                                    $nameVal  = $attributes->Name."=".$attributes->Value;                       
                                     $str_temp .=$nameVal."#";              
                                }
                            }
            }else
            {
                $str_temp ="NA";                
            }
            return  $str_temp;
    }

    $arrpath =explode(",",$XmlPath);
    /*Reading and storing  arrpath[0] has the path of xml to be parsed*/ 
         $strG=read($arrpath[0]);
         $strC=read($arrpath[1]);
         $strB =read($arrpath[2]);

    setcookie($cid.'strE',$strG);
    setcookie($cid.'comstr',$strC);
    setcookie($cid.'basstr',$strB);

            (....)
```

in the same file am reading the cookie using the below code,

```
$read_str =$_COOKIE[$cid.'strE'].$_COOKIE[$cid.'comstr'].$_COOKIE[$cid.'basstr'];
```

after this process is done bottom.php will be called and for the first time loading is completed.As i said for the first time am not getting any value in $read_str, but if i refresh the page and do all the process again i am getting the value.

As SETCOOKIE will return TRUE incase of successfully setting cookie i tried putting it in an if-loop and it returned false even for the first time.

kindly assist me in finding where the problem exists!

Comment: `setcookie` only sets a cookie that your browser will receive, it does *not* modify `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: @DCoder Can you explain me please.

Comment: `setcookie` is used to *send cookies to the browser*, `$_COOKIE` represents cookies *already received by the server*. Understand the difference. If you need to access the newly set cookie through `$_COOKIE`, you have to manually put it there.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `isset` to check if a cookie exists and then try setting one.

Something like this.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['yourcookie'])) {
    setcookie('yourcookie', 'Some data !');
    $_COOKIE['yourcookie'] = 'Some data !';
}
echo $_COOKIE['yourcookie'];
```

Comment: i tried isset before setting the cookie but it returns false, cookie is not set. Why am i not getting the value in first time but getting after i reload the page?

Comment: when you check for first time for a cookie with `isset`, it will definitely return false (when the code is running for the first time)., and in second time, the isset returns true, and you can either modify the cookie value or do what you want.

Comment: Which means the same page where i set cookie has to be called again inorder to retrieve the value?? or any otherway i can get the value i mentioned in question?

Comment: Nope not really, Once you have set the cookie, you can access it from any page. say if the above code is on page1.php, and on page2.php.. you can just use `$mycookieval=$_COOKIE['yourcookie']`, this will print `Some data !` which we set on the first page.

Comment: i moved the setcookie to top.php and tried reading using       ($read_str =$_COOKIE[$cid.'strE'].$_COOKIE[$cid.'comstr'].$_COOKIE[$cid.'basstr'];) but still am not getting the value unless i reload the page

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here looking for an answer as well. Here's the deal.

When you set a cookie it can only be accessed on the next page load, that is why you can't access it after you set it. If you really need to work with the cookie data right away, you could set the value directly in global cookie such as:

```
$_COOKIE['my_cookie'] = 'i am a cookie';
```

Use `setcookie()`just the same so you can set expiration, domain, etc..